# changing how the array is outputted

Tags: java, arrays, json

So I am using the GSON Libary to output my user inputted arrays to a .json file and I was wondering how do I code it in a way so it outputs the infomation without the annotations to make it easier to import the .json file back into the array?

I will show the code and how the array is outputted so it makes more sense.

Postit.java

```
package postit;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Postit {
public static Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int MenuOption = 0;

    NewStorage G = new NewStorage();    // Case 1 Object



    while(MenuOption != 3){



        System.out.println(

                "\n--------Note System-------\n" +
                        "----------------------------\n" +
                        "1.   Create a Note \n" +
                        "2.   View Notes \n" +
                        "3.   Close Program\n" +
                        "4.   Write File\n" +
                        "5.   Test code\n" +
                        "----------------------------\n");

        MenuOption = menu.nextInt();
        menu.nextLine();

        switch (MenuOption) {

            case 1:


                G.printinfo();
                G.Notestore();

                break;

            case 2:

                G.viewNotes();
                G.printNotes();
                break;

            case 3:

                System.out.println("Program is closing");
                System.exit(0);


                break;

            case 4:


                G.writeFile();


                System.out.println("Done.");
                break;

            case 5:

                G.Gsontest();
                break;

           default:

                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");

                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

NewStorage.java

```
package postit;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

class NewStorage {
Gson gson = new Gson();


ArrayList<Note> NoteArray = new ArrayList<Note>(20);

public void printinfo() {
    System.out.println("--- Fill note here  ---");
}



public void Gsontest() {
    String userJson = gson.toJson(NoteArray.toString());
    gson.toJson(userJson, System.out);
    }

public void Notestore() {
    System.out.println("Enter the note ID you wish to attach the note with\n\n");
    String inputIDnote = Postit.menu.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your note\n\n");
    String noteDescription = Postit.menu.nextLine();
    NoteArray.add(new Note(inputIDnote, noteDescription));
}

public void viewNotes() {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of the note you wish to view.");
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NoteArray.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((count++) + ": " + NoteArray.get(i).inputIDnote);
    }
}

public void printNotes() {

    int count = Postit.menu.nextInt();
    Postit.menu.nextLine();

    System.out.println(count + " " + NoteArray.get(count));
}

public void writeFile() throws IOException {

    try
        (Writer writer = new FileWriter("src\\Output.json"))
        {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            for (int i = 0; i < NoteArray.size(); i++) {
                gson.toJson(NoteArray.get(i).toString(), writer);
            }
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

note.java

```
package postit;

class Note {



String  inputIDnote;
String  noteDescription;
    public Note(String inputIDnote, String noteDescription) {
   this.inputIDnote = inputIDnote;
   this.noteDescription = noteDescription;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\n\n" + "ID: " + inputIDnote + "\n\n" + " Description: " + 
 noteDescription;
 }

 }
```

The .json file is outputted like this

"\n\nID: ID1\n\n Description: NOTE1""\n\nID: ID2\n\n Description: NOTE2"

With the following values added

ID = ID1 Description = NOTE1
ID = ID2 Description - NOTE2

Comment: You should not be calling toString() on your NoteArray here String userJson = gson.toJson(NoteArray.toString()); Just pass the instance to the toJson() method.

Comment: are you referring to the writefile function?

Comment: Well I changed the line to this

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                String userJson = gson.toJson(NoteArray.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < NoteArray.size(); i++) {
                    gson.toJson(userJson, writer);

Still outputs the same infomation

Comment: Remove the toString() everywhere. You do not need the toString() when using Gson.

Comment: Jarrod Roberson you have marked this as a duplicate of a question that does not have an accepted answerer and is arguably asking a different question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use Gson to serialize your array do this.

```
public void writeFile() throws IOException {
    try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("src\\Output.json")) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            gson.toJson(NoteArray, writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How come the down vote?

Comment: I know, this code seems to output what i was looking for. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am not certain Jarrod Roberson actually read the question he marked as a duplicate of this one. Oh well. Glad I could help.